# Module to remove inactive customers

Tags: magento2, customer-account, third-party-module, remove

Can anyone recommend a good free or paid module which will fit the following scenario please?

A customer has created an account but has never placed an order, so this account must be removed after 5 years of inactivity.

The only modules I know of, only allow the customer to remove the account themselves when they're logged in - instead of the customer account being automatically removed etc.

Cheers

Comment: I can create it if you want https://www.fiverr.com/share/KeVzN4

Comment: @WaqarAli I appreciate that :) but the thing is, I can actually develop it myself.
However I'm just looking into for this on behalf of a client who is looking for a module recommendation. Thank you again though for the offer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it easyly with a custom module.
I did a fast customization here which has a cron to remove once a day olders customers. Besides that one Data Patch to remove in moment of module instalation.

Module: Ritter_RemoveOlderCustomers

registration.php

```
<?php

use Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;

ComponentRegistrar::register(ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, 'Ritter_RemoveOlderCustomers', __DIR__);
```

etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Ritter_RemoveOlderCustomers"/>
</config>
```

etc/crontab.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Ritter_RemoveOlderCustomers"/>
</config>
```

Helper/Data.php

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Ritter\RemoveOlderCustomers\Helper;

use Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerRepository;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection;

class Data
{
    const CUSTOMER_TIME = '- 5 years';

    /** @var CollectionFactory */
    private $collectionFactory;

    /** @var ResourceConnection */
    private $resourceConnection;

    /**
     * @param CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
     * @param ResourceConnection $resourceConnection
     */
    public function __construct(
        CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        ResourceConnection $resourceConnection
    ) {
        $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
        $this->resourceConnection = $resourceConnection;
    }

    /**
     * Get customer id that never login
     * filtering by date >= 5 years
     * @return array
     */
    public function getCustomersNeverLogin()
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\Collection $customers */
        $customers = $this->collectionFactory->create();
        $from = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(self::CUSTOMER_TIME));
        $customers->addFieldToFilter('created_at', ['lteq' => $from]);
        $customerIds = $customers->getAllIds();

        $connection = $this->resourceConnection->getConnection();
        $select = $connection->select()->from(
            ['customer_log' => 'customer_log']
        );

        $data = $connection->fetchAll($select);

        $customersIdLastLogin = [];
        foreach ($data ?? [] as $customerData) {
            $customersIdLastLogin[] = $customerData['customer_id'];
        }

        return array_diff($customerIds, $customersIdLastLogin) ?? [];
    }

    /**
     * Get customers id that didn't log in the last 5 years
     * @return array
     */
    public function getOlderLoginsDate()
    {
        $from = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(self::CUSTOMER_TIME));
        $connection = $this->resourceConnection->getConnection();
        $select = $connection->select()->from(
            ['customer_log' => 'customer_log']
        )->where('last_login_at <=?', $from);

        $data = $connection->fetchAll($select);

        $customersOlderLoginDate = [];
        foreach ($data ?? [] as $customerData) {
            $customersOlderLoginDate[] = $customerData['customer_id'];
        }

        return $customersOlderLoginDate;
    }
}
```

Cron/RemoveOlderCustomers.php

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Ritter\RemoveOlderCustomers\Cron;

use Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerRepository;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use Ritter\RemoveOlderCustomers\Helper\Data;

class RemoveOlderCustomers
{
    /** @var Data */
    private $data;

    /** @var CustomerRepository */
    private $customerRepository;

    /** @var Registry */
    private $registry;

    /**
     * @param Data $data
     * @param CustomerRepository $customerRepository
     * @param Registry $registry
     */
    public function __construct(
        Data $data,
        CustomerRepository $customerRepository,
        Registry $registry
    ) {
        $this->data = $data;
        $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
        $this->registry = $registry;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $this->registry->register('isSecureArea', true);
        $neverLogins = $this->data->getCustomersNeverLogin();
        $olderLogins = $this->data->getOlderLoginsDate();

        $allIds = array_merge($neverLogins, $olderLogins);

        foreach ($allIds ?? [] as $id) {
            try {
                $this->customerRepository->deleteById($id);
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                //nothing
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

}
```

Setup/Patch/Data/RemoveOlderCustomersFirstRun.php

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Ritter\RemoveOlderCustomers\Setup\Patch\Data;

use Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerRepository;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\PatchInterface;
use Ritter\RemoveOlderCustomers\Helper\Data;

class RemoveOlderCustomersFirstRun implements DataPatchInterface
{
    /** @var Data */
    private $data;

    /** @var CustomerRepository */
    private $customerRepository;

    /** @var Registry */
    private $registry;

    /**
     * @param Data $data
     * @param CustomerRepository $customerRepository
     * @param Registry $registry
     */
    public function __construct(
        Data $data,
        CustomerRepository $customerRepository,
        Registry $registry
    ) {
        $this->data = $data;
        $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
        $this->registry = $registry;
    }

    public static function getDependencies()
    {
        return [];
    }

    public function getAliases()
    {
        return [];
    }

    public function apply()
    {
        $this->registry->register('isSecureArea', true);
        $neverLogins = $this->data->getCustomersNeverLogin();
        $olderLogins = $this->data->getOlderLoginsDate();

        $allIds = array_merge($neverLogins, $olderLogins);

        foreach ($allIds ?? [] as $id) {
            try {
                $this->customerRepository->deleteById($id);
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                //nothing
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Leandro Ritter, that's perfect thank you! :)